# Cast Any variable to type of another variable

Tags: swift, casting

I want to compare two variables (`a` e.g. a `String` and `b`) of type `Any` therefore I first want to cast the `b` to the type of `a` like this

```
let typedString = "string_value"
let a = typedString as Any
var b: Any = // irrelevant what actual value it has

let aType = type(of: a)
guard let castedB = b as? aType else { // this is where the compiler comp(i)lains
    // can't cast b to type of a
    return
}
```

But unfortunately the compiler doesn't allow me to do that with the message

> Use of undeclared type 'aType'

Any suggestions on how to cast variable `b` to (previously unknown) type of variable `a`?

Comment: But what would you expect `castedB` to be statically typed as? The value of `aType` isn't known until runtime.

Comment: I wouldnt mind if the compiler still thinks it's Any (like the return valiue of type(of:), i just want it to be the right type on runtime

Comment: Take a look at Hamish's link; I'm pretty sure this is a dupe (and will mark it that way unless you believe there's more to it that I'm missing). The answer is that you can't do this is Swift. `castedB` must be of a known type at compile-time, and this can't achieve that.

Comment: Yep guys & @Hamish thx for the link. This is the same issue

Comment: It is *always* the correct type at runtime – casting just lets you tell the compiler that it's of a given type. Having `castedB` typed as `Any` would be useless, as the compiler doesn't know anything more about `b` than it did originally.

Comment: But do you have any suggestion on how to compare two Any variables then?

Comment: You can't. You'll need to rethink your problem. There may not even be a meaning of "equal" for some types (this is actually true of *most* types; things that *can* be equated are the smaller group). As an example, there is no way in Swift to discuss whether two closures (`(T) -> ()` for example) are equal or not. (I'm not making a deep type-theory argument here; it is possible to invent programming languages where this is possible, but not in Swift).

Comment: Okay, too bad. Thanks guys